# Excel: Use table from one sheet in a different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a  table in an Excel sheet; the table and sheet are both called "LTIP_RD_COND_CURRENT_VW".

The table's source is a *[Microsoft Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylzq6.png)* via an ODBC connection to an external database.

[image]

[image]

---

I want to use the table data in a separate sheet within the same Excel file.

[image]

[image]

How can I use the table from one sheet in a different sheet?

I tried typing `=LTIP_RD_COND_CURRENT_VW` in a cell. But when I hit enter, the result is just an arbitrary number: 16094.

Comment: Do you want to use the CELL function? https://www.automateexcel.com/functions/cell-formula-excel/

Answer (score 2):

There are two good options here.

1. Create a Power Query on your table.

Select any cell in the table, then use Data>Get & Transorm Data>From Table/Range.

Work in the Power Query Editor to remove the columns you don't need and reformat the table as required, then use "Home>Close & Load to" to select where to put the result of the query.

2. Use a dynamic array formula.

You can use FILTER to filter out the columns you don't want.

[image]

You pass the table name, or the table name and [#All] if you want the headers as well as the argument to the first parameter.

The second parameter should be a single row of TRUE/FALSE values.

You can either use an array typed in such as {TRUE,FALSE,TRUE} as in the first example, or you can build that array with conditional statements as shown in the second example.

The plus operator indicators "OR". If you want "AND", then you would use an asterisk in its place.

Answer (score 1):

First described is a "regular" way of doing this. A much better way is at the end.

Excel's Tables can be referred to in their entirety with, for instance:

```
=LTIP_RD_COND_CURRENT_VW[#All]
```

but only as a range, so to speak:  the table data minus the "Table-nicity` of it.

Which might be all you need, and without the difficulties of anything else.

But if you want the created range to be a Table also, it becomes a little more work.

First problem is the headers. Table headers are, in ALL circumstances on GGE, TEXT only. So you place, say, the formula above and then tell Excel to make it a Table. And Excel immediately either makes the first row text headers or exits the making it a Table process. If you let it make a Table of it, well, the formula is in the first header cell so it becomes text and the Table has nothing.

Instead, copy and paste the headers from the source Table. Whichever columns those might be.

Then in the first row of each column place the following formula. Modify references as necessary:

```
=A7
```

The Table nature of the Table will propagate the formulas down as far as there is data in the source Table so just the first row of formulas in required.

Once they are in place, use `Ctrl-T` to make it a Table and be sure it includes that it has headers. Nice two row Table. Then grab the little triangle marker in the lower right corner of the lower right cell of the new Table and drag it down, down, down... until you either recognize the last line of data from the source table, or you begin seeing `#REF!` errors. Before letting go, make sure to run it back up so those all disappear and just good-looking material is showing, then let go. Nice filled in Table that will expand and... NO... your derivative Table will NOT expand and contract to match your source Table.

I do not know of a way to force that to happen, though someone else may. Without such a way, each time the source Table changes, you will have to drag the bottom of your Table down to where it must be to include the new rows, or up if some were removed. Similar work will be needed for when rows are deleted or inserted.

It's no panacea.

(Curious about the "16094" value... one supposes it happens to occur in your data, but as put, it creates the tantalizing thought that it might be... interesting.)

**For a better way:**

Do another query, just this time with the source Table as its source and the Table you wish to display as its output. You clearly already know how to use Power Query as you have this query already running.

Panacea-time.